# How to undo the group effect of having clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, having

[image]

[image]

Query :For each pilot who is certified for **more than three aircraft**, find the eid and maximum cruising range of the **each aircraft** he/she is certified.

Query I wrote :

```
select certified.eid,cruising_range
from certified join employee 
on employee.eid=certified.eid
join aircraft
on certified.aid=aircraft.aid
having count(certified.eid)>3;
```

**Output:**

[image]

it shows only one cruising range, but pilot with **id 10** is certified for **4 aircraft** . how to get those other rows ?

Comment: You need a GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is really in two parts:

1. Find the pilots who are certified on more than three aircraft

   ```
   SELECT eid FROM certified GROUP BY eid HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
   ```
2. Find the cruising range of those aircraft

   ```
   SELECT eid, cruising_range FROM aircraft JOIN certified USING (aid) ...
   ```

Combining the two:

```
SELECT eid, cruising_range FROM aircraft JOIN certified USING (aid) JOIN (
  SELECT eid FROM certified GROUP BY eid HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
) t USING (eid)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `group by certified.eid` .

> The count is an aggregate operator, which makes only one row returned
>   (without a group by clause)

```
select certified.eid,cruising_range
from certified join employee 
on employee.eid=certified.eid
join aircraft
on certified.aid=aircraft.aid
group by certified.eid`
having count(certified.eid)>3;
```

without group by aggregate function return only one row

Comment: It doesn't give the required output. in output id 10 would be repeated for times because there is 4 different aircrafts with different cruising range.

Comment: try group by certified.eid`,employee.eid @Balraj

Comment: I think you need to look at question again, i dont want to group anything . also your code doesn't run. am i supposed to put parentheses for group by column. @Rahautos